# Finding the amount of lines and empty lines in a list of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to be able to find the number of  lines and empty lines in a list of strings.

```
text = [
'Hi my name is bob',
'hi my name is jill',
'hi my name is john',
'hi my name jordan']
```

I have come up with

```
def stats(text: list):
    for i in range(len(text)):
        lines = (i + 1)
    for i in text:
        if i == '\n':
            print(range(len(i)))
```

finding the amount of lines works but finding the amount of empty lines does not work

Do I need to use these methods?

```
result = []
.append()
```

also what methods could I use to be able to print out the avg characters per line and average character per non-empty line?

Comment: What would you consider an empty line in your `text` variable? None of those look empty to me

Comment: `def stats(text: list):` correct?

Comment: empty line as in '\n'

Comment: Well, `len(text)` gives you the number of items (lines) in `text`; `sum(1 for x in text if x.strip() != '')` counts non-empty lines. Is this homework?

Comment: its a problem i got wrong and have no idea how to approach it

Answer (score 1):

Maybe simply use list comprehension? Here is a demo:

```
>>> f = open('file')
>>> l = f.readlines()
>>> l
['my name is bob\n',
 '\n',
 'hi my name is jill\n',
 'hi my name is john\n',
 '\n',
 '\n',
 'hi my name jordan\n']   # there is 3 *empty lines* and 4 non-empty lines in this file
>>> len([i for i in l if i == '\n'])
3
>>> len([i for i in l if i != '\n'])
4
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple version (that doesn't rely on the input even being a list; will work with any iterable):

```
def stats(lines):
    empty = 0
    for total, line in enumerate(lines, start=1):
        empty += not line.rstrip('\r\n')
    return total, empty
```